# Single-purpose Methods

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to find information on single purpose methods, in particular their advantages and disadvantages, in Java.  I have read my text book, and "Googled" it, but not finding information on single purpose methods.  My questions:

What is a single purpose method?

What are some advantages or disadvantages?

Where can I find information on single purpose methods so that I may form my own opinion?

Feel free to answer any of the three.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the concept. It's not a type of method, rather just a guideline, which states that methods should have one and only one purpose.

Comment: Thank you!  I was misunderstanding the concept.  This helps tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are many terms for this idea that a function should only do one thing. I for one learned the term functional or procedural abstraction. Regardless the term, the idea is that a function should do only one thing and abstract the way of doing something. The idea of abstraction is widely used in it not only in programming. Look at the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29